# creating highchart from json file

Tags: json, highcharts

I am trying to create a basic column hich charts but I am not seeing where I am going wrong. Below is the code I use (the part I am having problems with):

```
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
<script> 

$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON("http://23.251.135.197:8080/yii/testdrive/protected/views/site/sqldata/analysis_stab_app.php", function(json){

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Stab events'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'number of events'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> <br/>',
                shared: true
            },

                series: arrays

        });
        });
    });

    </script>
</div>
```

The php file with json_encode outputs:

```
[{"Speed_high_below_1000":23,"Sink_rate_high_below_1000":20,"Speed_high_below_500":18,"Sink_rate_high_below_500":15,"Speedbrakes_below_1000":4,"Late land flaps":4,"Go around":2}]
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You have `series: arrays` in the highcharts config object, but I don't see any `arrays` variable in your code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Good of you catching that, I had that changed but it didn't really help. I've used both json and leaving it empty but haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the object you need to have "y" param, instead of custom names

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to be clear, do I need to change the custom names to instead become a y parameter within the array?

Comment: excatly, the value which should be draw, need to be y.